# Using window.location.hash and anchor tag on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that, on click, will link to an id on the page.

```
$(document).on('click', '.quiz-modal-close-label', function() {
window.location.hash = '#more-quizzes';
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<aside id='more-quizzes' class='col-xs-12 col-md-3 more-quizzes-container'> ...
```

On desktop it works. In Chrome mobile inspector it works. But on mobile, the `#more-quizzes` does not get appended to the URL. What could the cause be?

Comment: what device and browser? Sounds highly improbable on most

Comment: @charlietfl Nexus6/Android/Chrome, both updated. You are saying it is very unlikely anchor tags work on mobile for most browsers, or that it is improbable to add the hash using js?

Comment: am saying that using hash is so very very common that there shouldn't a be a problem setting it. Try `alert(location.href)` right after you set it

Comment: The plot thickens. Alert does not show, but then, I did an alert site wide, and that didn't show either. However, other JS still works, there are no errors, and the alerts show on desktop. Ver weird.

Comment: Using some sort of framework that might be interfering? Or any other event handlers that might be preventing event propagation?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the mobile browser version you are using doesn't support this?

Try checking the MDN compatibility matrices:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location]

and

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange]

Also, have you verified that your event is getting fired when you touch the button on mobile?